# Is there a way to automatically select a range and set it up as a dictionary?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if, in VBA, if there's a more streamlined way of populating a dictionary based on data already in the worksheet? Or should I just loop through it upon the opening of the document or manually code that into the VBA editor.

Thank you

Comment: If you want a dictionary then you have to loop in some way. If you are using ADO you can simply use recordset for data.

Comment: Are you talking about the spelling dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary as a data set. The idea is to automatically check values against a table without having the macro have to bounce back and forth between sheets

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use the Dictionary without coding

Comment: I know you can't use a dictionary without coding. I can code it in- I'd hope that there was a shorthand way to create and input the values in select columns without having to loop through it. I've got a lot of processes at the start of the program- one quick import into the tables might have been more expedient

Comment: You can import a range directly into an array. Why do you need it in a dictionary?

Comment: It's for comparative values- where the info in column A will be the same and I'm checking the second values against column B. Using a dictionary seems to be the most automatic. Thank you

Comment: Dictionary is the fastest way and optimal, you can also use autofilter with a loop on the unique values of column A. And i answered a question with for comparing with countif on [SO Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237482/75104)